# Defining a Class: How to inheriting from object class

Tags: python, python-2.7

So this is my code, i am trying to get the Rectangle class to inherit from the object class. I don't understand what does it mean by the object class, and how to inherit it.

```
class Rectangle:

def __init__(self, coords, sizex, sizey):
    self._startx, self._starty = coords
    self._sizex = sizex
    self._sizey = sizey

def getBottomright(self):
    '(%s, %s)' % (self._startx + self._sizex, self._starty + self._sizey)

def move(self, pos):
    self._startx, self._starty = pos

def resize(self, width, height):
    self._sizex = width
    self._sizey = height

def __str__(self):
    return '((%s, %s), (%s, %s))' % (self._startx, self._starty, self._startx + self._sizex, self._starty + self._sizey)


r = Rectangle((2, 3), 5, 6)
print str(r)
'((2, 3), (7, 9))'
r.move((5, 5))
print str(r)
'((5, 5), (10, 11))'
r.resize(1,1)
print str(r)
'((5, 5), (6, 6))'
r.getBottomright()
(6, 6)
```

Comment: Just do `class Rectangle(object)`

Comment: Note that in Python 2.x, you _always_ want to inherit from `object` (unless you have something else to inherit from), because otherwise you get an "old-style class", which has various quirks and limitations you don't want to learn about.

Comment: Note that in addition to declaring `class Rectangle(object)`, you will also need to indent the `def` blocks to make them methods on the class rather than global functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inherit from `object`, just put it in parenthesis after the class name:

```
class Rectangle(object):
```

Basically, the syntax for inheritance is as so:

```
class ClassName(object1, object2, ...):
```

In the above code, `ClassName` inherits from `object1`, `object2`, and any other classes you place in there (note that if there is more than one class in the parenthesis, it is called "multiple inheritance").

For reference, here is an in-depth tutorial about classes, inheritance, and the like:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Also another question, the code is actually wrong now that i can check, r.getbottomright is returning None. Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: Yea.  You need to return: `return '(%s, %s)' % (self._startx + self._sizex, self._starty + self._sizey)`.  Also, make sure your indentation is good.

Answer (score 2):

To inherit from `object` (or any other class), just put the class to inherit from in parentheses after the class name where you're defining it.

```
class Rectangle(object):
    pass #class stuff goes here.
```

As to your other question, the `object` class is most basic class in Python. Generally speaking, all classes should inherit directly from `object`, unless they inherit from something else.

However, it sounds like you're confused about what inheritance and classes actually *are*, which means you probably ought to go read up on [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in general, and [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) in particular.